# Rules only firing at the end when replaying with drools

Tags: testing, drools

I'm writing a data backtester / replayer for a Drools application. I have a stream of events that are timestamped, and I'm trying to write a unit test that replays these events from start to finish. I'm using a pseudo-session clock in order to control the passage of time in my tests, as the rules I'm testing use time-based conditions (e.g. window:time). I am also using a stateful KIE session in my test application (`EventProcessingOption.STREAM`)

From my testing however, I'm finding that RHS of my test rule only triggers once, *after* all of the data has been inserted, even though the event data and rule conditions should trigger the rule to fire sooner in the data stream. This is problematic, as this means I'm not able to accurately test the side effects of the system.

A rough pseudo code of the test application is:

```
insert(eventA)
advanceTimeTo(eventA.timestamp)
insert(eventB)
advanceTimeTo(eventB.timestamp) // rule RHS should trigger here for e.g.
insert(eventC)
advanceTimeTo(eventC.timestamp)

// However, rule triggers after eventC, and state of the KIE facts is after eventC has been inserted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Likely, your live application and your testing framework, deal differently with the `fireAllRules()` (or `fireUntilHalt()`).

Which by the way if confirmed is problematic, as it will be more difficult for you to replicate during testing, the exact time of rule firing in a deterministic way.
In case, you might therefore consider to unify the way session reference clock and fire rule invocation works for both the testing and your live application. (If reproducibility and determinism in replay, is a strict requirement).

Comment: +1 especially for the last paragraph. the closer you can get to 'production' the better; not only does it make debugging easier, but as you develop new functionality there's nothing worse than discovering that this new cool thing you built and tested and got through QA has gone and blown up production.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute `session.fireAllRules()` after time advance.

**[Not a Bug]** [DROOLS-2240](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-2240) Timer rules with pseudo clock don't fire

> This is not how the psuedo-clock is supposed to work. Conversely time conditions are evaluated once at each discrete jump so what happens when you do 10 seconds jump is that the timestamp *for the next expected rule firing is compared with the current time* and if it's lower the rule fires once and that's all.